# Generic iterable extending specific interfaces

Tags: typescript

```
export type BreadcrumbsChildren<T> = Iterable<
  (T extends BreadcrumbsItemProps) | (T extends BreadcrumbsBaseItemProps)
>;
```

Trying to create an iterable that accepts a generic that extends (not intersect) one of two interface types that exist. Been trying to find an example everywhere but there aren't any.

I understand that there is an issue with the syntax in this case and how TypeScript structures things.

```
Exported type alias 'BreadcrumbsChildren' has or is using private name ''.ts(4081)
```

Comment: Did you want `type BreadcrumbsChildren<T extends BreadcrumbsItemProps | BreadcrumbsBaseItemProps> = Iterable<T>;`?

Comment: @Unmitigated There we have it! Post an answer and I'll accept!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a union for the generic constraint.

```
type BreadcrumbsChildren<T extends BreadcrumbsItemProps | BreadcrumbsBaseItemProps> = Iterable<T>;
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get why you want to place the condition on the second part of the type instead of the first.

The most straightforward solution is a union, but I guess you don't want it since you asked to avoid an "intersection".

```
type BreadcrumbsChildren<T extends (BreadcrumbsItemProps | BreadcrumbsBaseItemProps)> = Iterable<T>
```

An alternative thing you can do is say that if the type does not `extends` the interface you want the type is never:

```
type BreadcrumbsChildren<T> = T extends BreadcrumbsItemProps ? Iterable<T
> : T extends BreadcrumbsBaseItemProps ? Iterable<T> : never;
```

This notation usually is used when you need some logic based on multiple generics.
However, in this scenario is less optimal because it allows you to pass other interfaces to `BreadcrumbsChildren` but it won't allow you to assign a value:

```
// It allows you to pass "string" but when you assign something the error is similar to:
// Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type 'never'.
const x: BreadcrumbsChildren<string> = []
```